# UITableVIewController Show Text on Scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I want to display some text (I guess in the header section) of a tableview when the user scrolls it. Kind of like pull to refresh, but just a message. Does anyone know the best way to do this? I Just want to show text so I think the UIRefresh control is kind of out. Thanks!

Comment: It's not a common UI pattern probably means there's a reason why. Would have to detect the scrolling of the table, increase the size of the header view at the same time the table is doing it's thing scrolling cells. Sounds like a recipe for choppy difficult code. I'd create a view with my message. Position it above the tableview and make it's height 1px and visibility to hidden. Detect the scrolling, and switch its visibility to visible and animate setting the frame of the view to the size it needs to be (from the bottom up). If reasonable let me now and I'll try to provide an example.

Comment: Of course if the message can be placed in position and hidden it would be just a simple detect scrolling and set label to be visible. Is this what you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by, "When the user scrolls?" Do you want a message to be displayed in the header `tableViewHeader` instead of a `UIRefreshControl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to place a message in the `tableViewHeader`:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 20)];
    label.text = @"Hello, World!";
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = label;
    [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-label.bounds.size.height, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
}
```